# Multiple reducers Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, reducers

How can we apply more than 2 reducers to an Image?

The following link shows for 2 reducers
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_intro

But the following won't work:

```
// Load a Landsat 8 image.
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1/LC08_044034_20140318');

// Combine the mean and standard deviation reducers.
var reducers = ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
  reducer3: ee.Reducer.max(),
  sharedInputs: true
});

// Use the combined reducer to get
var stats = image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: reducers,
  bestEffort: true,
});

print(stats);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`combine` always combines two reducers, but you can combine a combination with another reducer. So, modify your script like so:

```
var reducers = ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
  sharedInputs: true
}).combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.max(),
  sharedInputs: true
});
```

to get:

```
B1_max: 23368
B1_mean: 9349.846011975142
B1_stdDev: 536.665332450372
B2_max: 24768
B2_mean: 8545.12421443731
B2_stdDev: 661.2107158731956
...
```